# volley JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQziv.jpg)

Hi, i'm trying to retrieve data from my server and i thing successfully getting it but not able to set data inside list, there is something wrong with my code which i can't figured out

**here's my code**

```
CustomVolleyJsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomVolleyJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, BaseURL.dboytoday_orders, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("Tag", response.toString());

                    today_order_models.clear();

                    try {


                        for ( int k=0;k<response.length();k++) {

                            JSONObject response1=response.getJSONObject(k);
                            String status = response1.getString("status");
                            String message = response1.getString("message");
                            //  String order = response.getString("order_id");

                            if (status.contains("2")) {

                                progressDialog.dismiss();



                                String user_name = response1.getString("user_name");
                                String user_phone = response1.getString("user_phone");
                                String user_id=response1.getString("user_id");


                                Today_Order_Model todayOrderModel = new Today_Order_Model();

                                todayOrderModel.setUser_id(user_id);
                                todayOrderModel.setUser_name(user_name);
                                //      todayOrderModel.setOrderid(order);
                                todayOrderModel.setUser_phone(user_phone);

                                today_order_models.add(todayOrderModel);
```

Comment: this parsing error

Comment: can anyone please explain what's wrong with my code

Comment: The response is JSONObj, not JSONEArray